# How to display all products of subcategories in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I create some categories and subcategories. Now, when I open categories, I see only subcategories, but I need to display all the products? Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: What are categories and subcategories? Taxonomy terms or something else? How are you showing them? Using views or again somehow differently? You must be more precise.

Comment: This is taxonomy terms, i use views

Answer (score 0):

With views and contextual filters. See the Taxonomy term view for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view. Select to show content (select content type).

- Select fields you want to display
- Select filter, if you want to select any (like: status=published)
- Expand "Advanced" section.
- Click on "Contextual Filters" -> Add
- Select: "Content: Has taxonomy term id (with depth)"
- Select depth (number child of child hierarchy)
- Expand: "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS IN THE URL OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED"
- Select "Validation criteria" -> Validator "Taxonomy term id"
- Select vocabulary if you want to limit your terms
- Multiple Arguments -> Single ID

Save the view, and configure it to display on taxonomy/term/* pages.

Hope it helps.